# Submitting a form via Ajax issue

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a page that dynamically generates a list of items, in each one of those items is a button that submits a from containing data from that item in the list (that is sorted and working). I submit the form via this code (Jquery):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){
        $('#readlatersubmit').ajaxForm( {
            target: '#result', 
            success: function() { 
                //$('#readlatersubmit').fadeOut('1000');   
                //$("#loader").fadeOut(); 
            } 
        }); 
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

When I click the button it submits the correct data and without the refreshing the whole page. The problem is that if I then go and click another one of the buttons in another one of the list items it goes to the form process page (does not submit via the Jquery).

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

**Edit**
This is what my form currently looks like:

```
<form id='readlatersubmit' action='RL.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='RLURL' value='".$item->get_link()."'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='RLTitle' value='".$item->get_title()."' />
    <input type='hidden' name='user-id' value='$loggedInUser->user_id' />
    <input type='image' src='images/ReadLaterRibbon_Active.png' name='submit' value='Submit' class='button' />
</form>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: `$('document')` does not match anything. What you want is `$(document)`

Answer (score 0):

Remove return false and let it check. because when you click on submit once, this will hold you on false but you don't need false, just remove return or use return true,

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function doitRun() {
        $('#readlatersubmit').ajaxForm( {
            target: '#result', 
            success: function() { 
                //$('#readlatersubmit').fadeOut('1000');   
                //$("#loader").fadeOut(); 
            } 
        }); 
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I have removed it and still nothing :( It still only uses the Jquery once?

Comment: please remove document ready and use any function, because this will call once when page load not again, because page need to load again if you will use it again. function doitRun() { $('#readlatersubmit').ajaxForm( {
            target: '#result', 
            success: function() { 
                //$('#readlatersubmit').fadeOut('1000');   
                //$("#loader").fadeOut(); 
            } 
        }); }

Comment: Ah! That makes sense! Is there anyway you could format that code in the comment so it is more readable to work out everything? Sorry to be a bother.

Comment: I have added that and the submit does not work at all, even first time. Is there something I might need to adjust in the form itself?

Thanks for all of this!

Comment: add me on skype adeelmughal4u